# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(n\alpha)}}{\ln(10)^n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(n\alpha)}}{\ln(10)^n}$$
For what $\alpha\in \text{Real numbers}$ does the series converge ?

What I did:

Using the nth root test we get:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(\sin{(n\alpha))^{1/n}}}{\ln(10)} = \frac{1}{\ln(10)}<1 \implies \text{convergence for all alpha} $$

Is it correct ?

Comment: Well, writing it $|\sin n\alpha|^{1/n}\le1$ might be more precise (to catch cases like $\alpha=0$), but the idea is more or less ok.

Comment: I would argue as follows: it is enough to show that $\sum |\sin(n\alpha)/\ln(10)^n|$ converges, but since $|\sin(n\alpha)|\le1$, we can furthermore reduce it to showing $\sum 1/\ln(10)^n$ converges. This is clear since $\ln(10)>1$.

Comment: Is it $1/\ln((10)^n)$ or $1/(\ln(10))^n$ ?

Comment: It converges for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. The sum is $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (\alpha  n)}{\log ^n 10}=\frac{\log 10 \sin \alpha }{1+\log ^2 2+\log 5 \log 20-\log 100 \cos \alpha }$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since proving that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sin(n\alpha))^{1/n} = 1$$
may be difficult, and for some $\alpha$ it's just not true, I'd first use the comparison test.
We have
$$ 0 \le \left|\frac{\sin(n\alpha)}{(\ln (10))^n}\right| \le \frac{1}{(\ln (10))^n} $$
Since $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln (10))^n} $$
is convergent (by the root test), then it means that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{\sin(n\alpha)}{(\ln (10))^n}\right| $$
is convergent, and this means that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n\alpha)}{(\ln (10))^n} $$
is convergent.